# sqlite. Table not creating

Tags: android

I'm trying to create table in the sqlite, but it is showing error that table cannot be created. I have a same code but the database and table name are different. the fields are same. Also one doubt. Can't i create the different table in the same database containing the same fields.

DbAdapter.java

the code is as below.

```
public class DbAdapter {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="bible1";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE="test1";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

    public static final String KEY_ID="_id";
    public static final String UNITS="units";
    public static final String CHAPTERS="chapters";

    private static final String CREATE_DATABASE="create table test1 (_id integer primary key autoincrement, units text not null, chapters text not null);";

    private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
    private static SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

    private Context context;

    //constructor

    public DbAdapter(Context c){
        context = c;
    }

    private static class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public SQLiteHelper(Context context){

            super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE);
            MakeUnits();
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

    public DbAdapter open() throws SQLException{
        try{
        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context);
        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }catch(NullPointerException ne){
            Log.e("error in creating the table", "bye");
        }

        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        sqLiteHelper.close();
    }

    public static long MakeUnits()
    {
        ContentValues insert1 = new ContentValues();
        insert1.put(UNITS, "Unit1");
        insert1.put(CHAPTERS, "CHAPTER1");
        return sqLiteDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,insert1);
    }

    public Cursor fetchAllNotes(){
        return sqLiteDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ID,UNITS,CHAPTERS}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private DbAdapter Database;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView listContent = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        Database= new DbAdapter(this);
        Database.open();

        Cursor c = Database.fetchAllNotes();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

It is giving error when the open() method is called. Couldn't figure it out.
in the logcat the error in the tag is that "error in creating the table"

Comment: Would you please give more information such as the error messages or call trace?

Comment: In the open() method of DbAdapter it is giving the error. If you send me your mail, then I can mail the code.

Comment: can't i have two tables with the same field name in the same database.?

Comment: I have another code which is same as it is and it is working. But this one not. So I'm in confusion.

Comment: You don't need anyone's email. You need to post the error messages that you get from logcat into your post. Use the edit option and add the message there.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call `sqLiteDatabase.insert` inside `MakeUnits`, but this `sqLiteDatabase` variable is null until after you call `getWritableDatabase`. You should pass `db` to `MakeUnits` and call insert on `db`, not on `sqLiteDatabase`.

Comment: Yeap this is it. I just ran some tests and this is the problem. BTW I hate you Tim rofl. I just spent like 10 minutes figuring this out xD

Comment: added the code changes. I always appreciate it when someone writes out the changes explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

database will be created only when you make a call to
         getWritableDatabase()/getReadableDatabase()

If you do not have permissions for a writable db, you will get a readable
        db.

```
    public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDB() {
        try {
            return helper.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return getReadableDB();
        }
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getReadableDB() {
        return helper.getReadableDatabase();
    }
```